# refresh data in view after ajax request symfony

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, twig, symfony

I'am new in Ajax and I intregated one ajax request. The purpose is one user can like, unlike an article. Look my code :

controller

```
public function likeAction(Request $request, Article $article, $slug)
{
    if (!$this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED')) {
        throw $this->createAccessDeniedException();
    }

    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $tokenStorage = $this->get('security.token_storage');
        $currentUser = $tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
        $likes = $article->getLikes();
        foreach ($likes->getUsers() as $user) {
            if ($user == $currentUser) {
                throw new \Exception('Vous aimez déjà cet article !');
            }
        }
        $likes->addUser($currentUser);
        $likes->setCount($likes->getCount() + 1);
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($article);
        $em->flush();

        $count = $article->getLikes()->getCount();
        return new JsonResponse(array('data' => $count));
    }
    return $this->redirectToRoute('pm_platform_view', array('slug' => $slug));
}
```

route

```
pm_platform_like:
    path:      /like/{slug}
    defaults:
        _controller: PMPlatformBundle:Article:like
```

view

```
<a class="btn btn-blue-grey" id="like" role="button"></a>
<span class="counter" id="counter">{{ article.likes.count }}</span>

    <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $(document).on('click', '#like', function (e) {
                $this = $(this);
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '{{ path('pm_platform_like', {slug: article.slug}) }}',
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    data: {},
                    success: function() {
                      //refresh article.count here 
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Currently the ajax request works and the "like" is persisted in database. But in my view nothing change, I have to "refresh" data, more precisly the like count attribute of article entity after the success of the ajax request. I need help for that.

Comment: You can recall function to get like count in ajax success condition.

Comment: I don't understand, can you write an example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `AJAX` request is already send total counts in response. So, all you need to update "counter" `div` with total like count.

`objResponse` holds response of `ajax` request and total like count would be stored in`objResponse.data` .

```
success: function(objResponse) {  // "objResponse" is response os ajax request
    $("#counter").html(objResponse.data);
    ^^
}
```

**Full Code**

```
<a class="btn btn-blue-grey" id="like" role="button"></a>
<span class="counter" id="counter">{{ article.likes.count }}</span>

<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $(document).on('click', '#like', function (e) {
            $this = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '{{ path('pm_platform_like', {slug: article.slug}) }}',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: {},
                success: function(objResponse) {  // "objResponse" is response os ajax request
                  //refresh article.countcounter here 
                  $("#counter").html(objResponse.data);
                  ^^
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

[Read more about ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have another ajax request that gets like count.

```
success: function(response) {
        //Recall function here that gets like count.
        fnGetLikeCount();
    }
```

**Edited:**

Can you post that function/ajax request that gets like count?

**Edit 2:**

Yes you can send response from controller and can assign/set that count in like lable/div or what ever you are using.

Comment: I don't have this ajax request. It think was possible to return the like count in the Json reponse (in the controller) ?

Comment: Please see edited answer, you can send response from controller.